# Get return values between these 2 classes

Tags: iphone, ios, class, return-value, uialertview

below is part of my code that I'm working on for quick reply on iOS 5, what i want to know is how to get the return values from the 3 methods under SBBulletinBannerItem to show up in the title and message fields accordingly, after i get this sorted out, I'm going to use the _appName return value to tell the gesture to open the quick reply alert if its sms, or to open the app if its anything else, I've tried quite a bit of things and can't seem to get it to work, thank you

```
%hook SBBulletinBannerController

- (void)_handleBannerTapGesture:(id)qreply

{
    qreply = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"Reply", nil];
    [qreply show];
    [qreply release];
}

%end

%hook SBBulletinBannerItem

- (id)_appName { return %orig; }
- (id)title { return %orig; }
- (id)message { return %orig; }

%end
```

Comment: What is this code from? it's not Objective C.

Comment: its using theos, its obj-c but it uses a preprocessor to add in the appropriate prefixes, and changes some values, such as %orig; which will pretty much do the original method without it being modified